# new line in one row bootsrap

Tags: css

i try to add 6 elements to one row with the following definition:

```
            <div class="row container"> 
             <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1"><a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://news.uwlax.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/FMF.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    </a></div>


              </div>...
            </div>
```

each line should contain 3 elements and the rest have to start new line.
actualy the new line stand and cover part of the first line.
see the attached screenshot.

any advice?

thanks.

Comment: First of all, do not use 'row' and 'container' on the same <div>.
'row' should always be a child of 'container'.
Second, define 3 <div>'s with 'col-md-4 col-sm-4' inside a <div class="row">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe i was not clear enough.
i inserted 6 columns into one row.
each one of them has the class "col-md-4" so i accepted 2 lines with 3 columns.
my problem was that the the bottom line rose slightly on top line.
i succeeded to solve it by giving the attribute margin-bottom:30px;

thank you for answering me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use 'row' and 'container' on the same `<div>`.
'row' should always be a child of 'container'.

Second, define 3 `<div>`'s with 'col-md-4 col-sm-4' inside a `<div class="row">`.

Repeat.